# Graphics driver update for Dell V3400

Tags: drivers, graphics, dell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the Intel Graphics driver in my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system)

My computer is Dell Vostro 3400. I installed Ubuntu 11.10 recently.

Here is the graphics card informations:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics > Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
```

How do I know if I need to update my graphics card driver and which one should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

Go "system settings", "Additional drivers", A list of drivers that are available for your Card will be shown, choose Recommended one and then activate it, Ubuntu will download the driver and install it on its own. restart your computer. You are done

Comment: I tried but there is no recommended graphic drivers.