# How do I install the Intel Graphics driver in my system?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel

Can someone help me out and explain or point me in the right direction on how to check video drivers and see if my video card running okay?

I had 10.04 installed on my Thinkpad r61 with Compiz Manager and life was great, until the machine took water damage. I bought an ASUS (X54H) since and am trying out 12.04, but the desktop just doesn't look right.

I always struggled with video driver installation. There are no proprietary drivers available in the hardware manager.

When I run `lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

I will greatly appreciate your help. I want to use Linux more, but like I said video drivers appear to be my biggest concern. I have also tried 12.04 on my desktop PC, but again failed to configure video card, so switched back to Windows 7.

Comment: Please see my answer in this post : http://askubuntu.com/questions/299373/how-to-install-drivers-for-switchable-graphics-for-hp-dv6-7040tx/299383#299383

Answer (score 43):

The Intel graphics driver is part of the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` driver package, which is installed on all Ubuntu systems by default. And since it isn't a proprietary driver package, it doesn't show up in jockey (aka the Hardware Drivers application).

Just to ensure it didn't get removed by mistake (very slim possibility), just run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

If the driver is installed, and you're still having issues with graphics on your desktop, then please file a bug report against the xorg package, using this terminal command:

```
apport-bug xorg
```

Comment: DO NOT INSTALL "install xserver-xorg-video-intel" AS IT MIGHT FREEZE YOUR LAPTOP AFTER YOU REBOOT. If you already done it, then follow these to clean up your system: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109400/mouse-and-keyboard-stopped-working-after-installing-xserver-xorg-video-intel

Answer (score 21):

Install `mesa-utils`, that might work.

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

it worked in my case. Read [this question posted by me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369449/unity-system-details-shows-that-my-driver-is-unknown-is-there-a-way-to-fix-this/369467#369467)

**before installing mesa-utils**
[image]

**after installing mesa-utils**
[image]

*mesa-utils is just not there in Ubuntu 12.10. It doesn't really matter.*

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 Dell Vostro 2420

Comment: Me too, Ubuntu 12.04 Dell Latitude D630

Comment: Where did you take this `Details` window?

Comment: @Dims Sorry but this is almost 4 years old, and I no longer use Ubuntu, so I don't remember.

Comment: @RegisteredUser what distro do you use now?

Answer (score 8):

[The Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072420) has a good description of how to install/update the Intel graphic driver in Ubuntu.

Extract of the pertinent part is as given below:

1. Open a terminal session by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run command to install ppa:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   ```
3. Install the drivers for your graphics chip

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
   ```

Ubuntu no longer uses xorg.config file. You will have to create this file in the next step and enter in values.

Create file `sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and edit it

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "Card0"
Driver "intel"
Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
EndSection
```

Save and close it. Restart your interface or just reboot you machine and go back to system settings - details - graphics and verify that your drivers are displayed.

Comment: This way damage my system  (UBUNTU 18.04) after boot in display manager keyboard not works and I can't login. I think this because `xserver-xorg-video-intel` deprecated and ubuntu not use it any more. This steps solve issue:   Reboot in grub give `1` as parameter to linux and start system in single user. `rm /etc/X11/Xorg.conf` and `apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel`. purge display manager then reinstall it. `apt install lightdm` to reconfigure display system.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1063032

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` returns `Error: ppa 'ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates' not found`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone, I actually was trying to load the MAME arcade emulator on my Lubuntu 15.10 and had to do the following since I got this error:

```
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error
```

I tried every suggestion in this thread, which didn't seem to resolve the issue. I also did the following:

tried the steps here:
So, the rub (if your Google-fu takes you here directly) to get this to work (on Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10):

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
# add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
# apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
# sed -i -e 's/"quiet splash"/"quiet splash i915.i915_enable_rc6=0"/g' /etc/default/grub
# update-grub
```

ALSO AFTER DOING THAT, I DID THIS:

Lubuntu System Menu [Bottom Left Corner] > Preferences > Additional Drivers 
Choose > Using Processor Microcode from Intel CPUs from intel-microcode [Proprietary]

INSTALLED THE OPTION ABOVE and NOW MY ERROR is gone!! I'm using a Dell Dimension 3000 which this worked/resolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Intel graphic processor I suggest the following

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-precise
```

Some issues with Intel Graphic Processors and suggested remedies can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402242/blank-screen-command-prompt-on-ubuntu-window-8-1-daul-boot-toshiba-laptop).