# How to update my Intel video card

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the Intel Graphics driver in my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system)

My video card is an Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics card

How do I update it?

Comment: Intel provides opensource drivers that are built into the kernel. There are no  proprietary drivers to install and update. If you edit your question and describe the problem, someone may be able to help.

Comment: Why is this closed, hardware and software are not the same thing? Why no link to the supposedly already existing answers?

Comment: Generally these were in lower end netbooks, there is no upgrade path apart from moving to another device.  These were problematic in any case, and often required troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

For Intel, the Open Source drivers that come with Ubuntu are always up to date. There is no need to update them (Very different than ATI or Nvidia for example). Ubuntu always comes with the latest Intel driver when it comes out and it also updates the Intel drivers with the most updated Open Source version available.

Intel is one of the many companies that work a lot in the Open Source world and delivers very good, stable drivers. They also do many updates every year for old and new video cards. Just in case you have any doubts, Ubuntu updates it's Intel video drivers to any still supported version of Ubuntu, that means that your 12.04 will have the latest open source Intel drivers.