# Unity system details shows that my driver is Unknown, is there a way to fix this?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

On running Ubuntu 12.10 through hard disk installation, the "details" app shows that graphics driver is unknown, as shown in the following image.
[image]

But when running an Ubuntu live usb, which contains Ubuntu 13.04,it shows that a driver is present

[image]
So, from this I think that I need to install the driver for corresponding graphics card, but I don't know how to.

btw my previous experiences with drivers are not good (when I was using windows xp),so I really need some help.

this is the output of the command

> glxinfo | grep render  .

[image]

Comment: how has the title changed???????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

installing mesa-utils worked

> sudo apt-get install mesa-utils .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your driver might already be there, you can try launching a game that requires a driver like minecraft, and if it starts you probaly have the driver there, but your computer just dont recognizes it.

Comment: if its there,there ought to be some way to find it.probably some command?
launching a game is not the right way,i think.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the Live session (second image) you are not seeing the same Graphics tab, but the general Overview tab which doesn't show the driver in use but the **Graphics card name**.

Second, the driver value indicates the string value of the mesa driver. Mesa is the *defacto* driver to render 3D applications in Linux. This is were is took the values in the first screenshot:

```
$ glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV515
```

[image]

As you can read, the "OpenGL renderer string" and the "Driver" are called the same. I doubt your Intel card supports this.

Comment: ok.But what should i do then?this is what i got                                                        aditya@aditya-desktop:~$  glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) G41 x86/MMX/SSE2
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
aditya@aditya-desktop:~$