# Second monitor is not detected after reconnecting Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Intel UHD

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, xrandr

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS yesterday and I was very excited to find out that when I connect my second monitor to the HDMI outlet Ubuntu detects and extends the display.

The monitor was later disconnected and when I reconnected it, Ubuntu failed to detect it.

My settings:

- Lenovo ThinkPad E15
- Intel UHD Graphics

What I tried:

- Rebooting and connecting the screen at different stages (after rebbot\before reboot)
- `xrandr --output VGA1 --auto`
- Adding the display manually as mentioned in [HDMI not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121132/hdmi-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04) and [HDMI1 is disconnected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796827/hdmi1-is-disconnected)
- Switching between `lighdm` and `gdm3`
- Checking the connection with more than one screen and more than one cable

my `xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.02  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Is there anything else I should try? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It happened again! and it seems that I had a problem with the xorg driver code. So I had to remove it and re-install it completely:

First I switched to non-gui mode on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Then I returned to the GUI mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and I rebooted the system.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that there might be a problem in the openGL settings under `hard info`

Found the solution in [Unity system details shows that my driver is Unknown, is there a way to fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369449/unity-system-details-shows-that-my-driver-is-unknown-is-there-a-way-to-fix-this)

Running this command fixed my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```