# Intel UHD second monitor is not detected after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I upgrade my ubuntu to 20.04LTS yesterday and when reboot the laptop, ubuntu failed to detect the second monitor.

I have card OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2), I followed the workaround posted [Second monitor is not detected after reconnecting Ubuntu 20.04LTS Intel UHD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285375/second-monitor-is-not-detected-after-reconnecting-ubuntu-20-04lts-intel-uhd) but it didn't work.
Any ideas?
Regards

Comment: Did you resolve this?