# Error running Ubuntu Emulator

Tags: ubuntu-touch, development, emulation

I'm getting the following error when I try to run Ubuntu Emulator,

`Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
[   10.407868] init: ureadahead main process (399) terminated with status 5`

I even tried to install the [Ubuntu Touch x86 Emulator](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/ubuntu-touch-x86-emulator-better.html) but I get the same error. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5):

Installing the new Intel graphics driver made my emulator work.

First I installed [Stable Open Source Graphic Drivers Updates](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/mesa) but I don't think made any changes to my situation.

Then I found an [answer on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system) to a question on how to install the drivers. The second answer did it for me which was to install `mesa-utils`

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```