# The System is Running in Low Graphics Mode 14.04 / Intel graphics card

Tags: drivers, graphics, dell, intel-graphics

After a software update through the GUI software update tool, my machine always boots into an error screen noting:

> The system is running in low graphics mode Your screen,
>   graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly.
>   You will need to configure these yourself.

I did find this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) somewhat useful, but there is not much information on how to fix for Intel graphics. My machine is a Dell Optiplex 9020 with Integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

So far I've tried several approaches, based on things I've read in other threads:

1. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
2. adding the  Xorg-Edgers PPA.
3. `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`
4. `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty`
5. `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

Comment: check here http://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: Alternatively, you can download and  use the driver from intel source https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads though you gotta have Ubuntu 14.04.2 that ships with default Utopic kernel.

Comment: that does not work either. I get the error from the intel-linux-installer that there is no intel i915 chipset