# No Graphics in Details in System Settings

Tags: graphics

I am using Lenovo G500 with 3rd gen core i3 processor and 4gb RAM. When I open Details in System Settings, it does not show me the graphics option instead, it shows this:
[image]

Comment: This is the expected view. What do you expect to see?

Comment: The source of confusion is that in previous Ubuntu's, there was a separate menu items titled "Graphics", as seen here: https://askubuntu.com/a/369474/722109

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open System Settings - click Details - click Overview ... now you can see graphics information.

[image]