# Latest intel video driver in Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: xubuntu, intel-graphics

i was wondering how can i check that my Xubuntu installation contains the latest intel video drivers?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system

Comment: @Fabby i actually ask for 18.04 which got out quiet recently. The answers you are pointing too are old. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Mantzas: Some of the answers still apply though. New Ubuntu releases don't change every upgrade management procedure.