# How to install intel graphics drivers on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, 18.04, intel-graphics

I have download [intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.2_amd64.deb](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-graphics-update-tool/intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.2_amd64.deb) from [here](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-graphics-update-tool/)
but when i was intalling it it dont work, notice that I am so beginner with ubuntu, any help please?

Comment: You don't need to install these drivers. They are intended for 16.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 are they instead installed on ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: There are no special drivers you need to install for Intel graphics.

Comment: @dobey i thought that my ubuntu 18.04 is slow because of that; any suggestion please ?

Comment: The suggestion is to write a new questing describing you REAL problem. The answer to the existing question has been done: "Don't install these drivers".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Intel Graphics driver in my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system)