# Keyboard stopped working after apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Tags: keyboard, xorg, touchpad, synaptics

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 and found the two-finger scrolling way too fast. So I followed the instructions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120045/touchpad-two-finger-scroll-too-fast)
and ran

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

But that required `xserver-xorg-core`, so I installed that as well. I rebooted and, once X started, I had no keyboard, but the mouse was working.

So I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109400/mouse-and-keyboard-stopped-working-after-installing-xserver-xorg-video-intel) and it seemed very similar to my case. However, my grub menu boot allowed only for a recovery boot with no internet access. So, while I could remove the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`, I had no way to reinstall the `ubuntu-desktop` and `xserver-xorg`.

I could still boot the machine, but maybe due to the above inability to reinstall, as soon as I logged in in X, I was thrown out again, to the login screen.

The second thread mentioned that ownership of `~/.Xauthority` in my home folder could be the reason, but I had no such file!

In the end, I had to reinstall from the ISO – no big deal as it was a new install. I still have no `~/.Xauthority` in my home folder. And now I'm quite hesitant to install input drivers – without any way to ssh into my machine, I'm helpless without a keyboard!

Comment: If you "just installed" it, wouldn't it be easier and faster to re-install on this case and go about solving the scrolling issue via built-in settings or some other method, if possible?

Comment: The built-in settings that Ubuntu comes with lets me choose the speed of the touchpad cursor, and lets me turn the two-finger scrolling on or off. However, it does not let me choose the scrolling _speed_. Hence why I tried the solution mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was completely removing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

1. Activate the on-screen keyboard (Settings => Universal Access => Screen Keyboard)
2. Removing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

   ```
   sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
   ```
3. Installing `xserver-xorg-input-all`

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
   sudo apt ugrade
   ```
4. Restarting my system

   ```
   reboot
   ```

Comment: That would have worked if I'd known to activate on-screen keyboard to remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

But since I did that from a regular terminal, I was from there unable to log into X – I was just thrown out. And the grub terminal had no internet access, so I couldn't install anything.

Comment: This worked for me but luckily I did not have to uninstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics since this driver is necessary to use the touchpad on my lenovo

Comment: It works for me. Thanks a lot