# How can I install Intel graphics driver in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

Is Intel graphics driver auto-installed in Ubuntu? I want to see it. Is there any command line to check it out?

My desktop icons looks big and some web pages tab are not showing text completely.

Output of `lshw -C video`:

```
*-display 
       description: VGA compatible controller 
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller 
       vendor: Intel Corporation 
       physical id: 2 
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 
       version: 06 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom 
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 
       resources: irq:28 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I think it is a video driver problem. So I think I need to install drivers. How do I install that?

Comment: `lsmod` will list your kernel modules (drivers), though I'd use `sudo lshw -C video` to list your hardware (of class video) and look for the module being used in the 'driver='  configuration line.  For most intel drivers, intel themselves add them to the linux source code so as long as your *unstated* release contains a kernel with driver for your hardware - you're good. This doesn't apply to all *intel* cards, but release (and its kernel) is the largest clue (along with your video card & it's age)

Comment: Output i got. 


sudo lshw -C video


  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

Comment: The drivers are installed as they typically are for Intel graphics.

Comment: Open Ubuntu Software Store > Add-ons > Hardware Drivers. There you Will find an universal OpenCL driver for Intel CPU

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Intel Graphics driver in my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system)