# After updating Ubuntu my box hangs on boot with this message: [ 66.670282] hdaudio hdauidoCOD3: Unable to configure, disabling

Tags: boot, updates

I was given a computer by a friend so I can teach myself Web/Android development to get a better job. This means I am my own IT dept for this computer. I have been able to figure out most problems by searching on line. Those I could not solve my friend was able to help me with. Since my last Ubuntu update (probably close to a year ago: I have been trying to solve this for awhile) my computer stalls while booting and displays the message `[   66.670282] hdaudio hdauidoCOD3: Unable to configure, disabling` This one has me stumped.

All of my searches for  `[   66.670282] hdaudio hdauidoCOD3: Unable to configure, disabling` have come back with people who also had problems after updating Ubuntu, but their message was some variant of `hdaudioCOD3 unable to bind the codec` The solutions for this similar, but different, message have not worked. It has been awhile since I have tried anything on this (life stepped up and demanded my full attention for awhile) so I don't remember everything have I tried, but I do know that one solution, adding nomodeset to a line in my grub file, was similar to what I had to do the with the previous system update, which also caused my computer to hang while booting. That time it fixed it. The solutions I found this time didn't work.

The lines not commented out in my grub file are as follows

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -1 -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFUALT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I have tried removing quiet splash, as some solutions for similar, but not identical, messages indicated. I have tried booting in safe mode and running the dpkg repair broken packages option. no dice.

If I choose the failsafeX option to run in failsafe graphic mode I get a message about screen resolution, I make a selection, and I get a gray screen and a hung computer.

If I resume the boot sequence from the safe mode menu I do get to the user selection screen, and can enter my password. I get a blank screen, a lot of HD action for a bit, then my computer hangs.

Can anyone point me to a resource that will help me better understand and address this issue, or does anyone know some step I can try?

Update: someone pointed out I forgot to include my OS version. The update took me up to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I am running on a Lenovo T430i laptop. (I doubt it is relevant, but it has been set up with a LAMP stack and Android Studio)

Comment: Oops. Thanks for pointing that out.  The upgrade that borked my computer took me up to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: Up to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS?   Are you sure?  This link shows the release of Ubuntu 22.04.3 ISO https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/  where installed systems upgraded before that date, so you're asking about a system that hasn't been updated since before early August 2023?   I suggest checking your details  (*I'd boot live media & look from there, or are you guessing 22.04.2?? maybe that was what you installed long ago? but if you applied upgrades, your system should have reported as 22.04.4 for awhile now*)  If you don't apply upgrades often, that maybe useful detail

Comment: Very sure:  used lsb_release -a. As I said, I worked on it for awhile, then life stepped up and demanded my full attention (Loved ones in hospitals and other "hilarious" hijinks).  This is the LTS (Long Term Service) version (released every two years, and supported for five years) not the standard version (released every six months and supported for nine months).

Comment: Try removing nomodeset and installitg `linux-generic-hwe-22.04`

Comment: FYI:  The 22.04 is your release; ie. the 2022-April LTS release, the extra .2/.3/.4 shows your upgrade level as for applying security fixes; .2 shows you very much behind; .4 is what you'd expect to see currently (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded before that ISO release date).  You are using Ubuntu 22.04, my *comment* was intended to be informational as it shows you're very behind on applying security fixes (*which you explained*) but it can also be clues as to ignored problem(s) [compounding]

Comment: Thank you guiverc! I had found an article that I thought might work before seeing your response. I am not sure if it played a part in solving the issue, so I include it here just in case. In this article

https://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system

I followed the instructions a ways down about installing graphics drivers and creating xorg.conf.  This removed the original error, but still hung the computer. I removed the xorg file, then saw your response and removed nomodeset from my grub file. It now boots just fine.  Thanks again!

Comment: I am still new to this. Is there something I need to do to mark this question answered, or to mark a comment as the accepted/working answer?

Comment: This is a Q&A or *Question and Answer* site, so until an answer is written & accepted by *original poster* the question remains open. I've just *flagged* the question as *problem went away* based on your prior comment (I could have marked it as *dup* to that question too), but *flag* has put question in *close queue* now. **Well done for solving your own issue !**

Comment: I remembered reading about selecting the check mark beside an answer I wished to accept (I forgot the bit about up-voting a comment instead of replying with a thank you ).  My problem is the only option I see on any comment is a flag icon allowing me to report the comment, the one thing I don't wish to do. The only place I have controls for up or down voting anything is my original post, which I can't use because I posted it. Nowhere, not even my OP, is there any box or check mark I can use to mark an answer as accepted. Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: We are telling you that in this case, we want you to go to the "Your Answer" box below, and write up a description yourself of each step that you did. Then click the checkmark on your answer. You can also @ me in a comment after for me to upvote it